# Excel new worksheet summaries

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a file in which data is entered in separate worksheets ( TABs ) per day. The layout is identical, Im looking for  solution to take a dynamic average from the last 1-3 months from those separate TABs. Every day a new TAB is being created, doing that by hand every month take way to much time. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample about the Workbooks?

Answer (score 0):

You may try with data > Consolidation or 3D formula

Example: you have following sheets
Jan
Feb
Mar
Summary

Assuming n each sheet, you have some numbers in A1

Goto Summary sheet enter following formula in A1
=average('Jan:Mar'!A1)

Answer (score 0):

To do that, we'll complete 2 steps:

## 1. Get the names of the first and last sheets

As I understand, you're adding a new sheet for each day. You'll need to make sure that the sheet's names are formatted the same way. For instance, let's assume the format is: DD-MM-YY (so August 1st 2020 will read 01-08-20).

In this step we would want to generate a **sheet range text** of the last 3 months (for example: *01-03-20:01-01-20*), to be used by INDIRECT formula to create a 3d formula (on the second step).

Let's assume that **LDATE** holds the **last** relevant date (so it can be a reference to another cell, or a formula like TODAY() or TODAY()-1 etc.).
Now, decide on what's the **first** relevant date. If it's 3*30 days before the last date, use:

```
=LDATE-3*30
```

Or, if it should be exactly 3 months before DATE, use:

```
=DATE(YEAR(LDATE),MONTH(LDATE)-3,DAY(LDATE))
```

Let's name this first date as **FDATE**.

Finally, this will be our formatted sheet range text (notice this assumes you've formatted the sheets' names as DD-MM-YY, just change to any other format if needed):

```
="'"&TEXT(LDATE,"DD-MM-YY")&":"&TEXT(FDATE,"DD-MM-YY")&"'!"
```

Value now should look like this: *'14-07-20:14-04-20'!*

Let's name the whole range as **SHEETRANGE**.

## 2. INDIRECT +  3d Formula

The INDIRECT function returns a valid reference from a given text string, and 'Sheet1:Sheet4'!A1:B2 is a range of all A1:B2 cells in all the sheets between Sheet1 to Sheet4.

So, the following will get the average of your dynamic range (assuming, for instance, you need the average of all A3 cells):

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(SHEETRANGE&"A3"))
```

Or, if we want to make it all happen in a cell (except for LDATE, which is up to you to define):

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("'"&TEXT(LDATE,"DD-MM-YY")&":"&TEXT(DATE(YEAR(LDATE),MONTH(LDATE)-3,DAY(LDATE)),"DD-MM-YY")&"'!"&"A3"))
```

Good luck!